# Regular Expression : Check string expression and then filter out value

Tags: c#, regex

Trying to figure out to match to a regular expression and then get a value from that string.

The string values would be something like this:
computerFileHardware20131211.pdf
computerFileSoftware20131322.pdf
computerFileEngineering20232.pdf

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"computerFile[^[A-Za-z]+$]([^0-9]+)\.pdf");
Match match = regex.Match("computerFileHardware20131211.pdf");
if (match.Success)
{
  Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is make sure I can match to the regular expression and then be able to filter out the number value. So for example for computerFileHardware20131211.pdf the number value would be 20131211.

I'm not very good a regular expressions. I think my first hurdle is figuring out the regular expression.  I read somewhere that you put parenthesis around the string you want to filter out. So that is why i have ([^0-9]+).

Comment: maybe easier for you will be spliting string with spaces, then every item check if it contains "computerFileEngineering" and end with ".pdf". If yes - then cut part of string between ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Well I could have a different regular expression each time.  I mostly want to filter out the number value.  So check if the regular expression is valid and then lift out the number value.

Comment: I also had experience something like you, but at the end finish without regex :)

Comment: I would love to do that.  But then I would be hard coding each type of file.  I would think there is more elegant solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like https://regex101.com/r/KWiAg0/1

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"computerFile[A-Za-z]+([0-9]+)\.pdf");
Match match = regex.Match("computerFileHardware20131211.pdf");
if (match.Success)
{
  Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Regular expressions can contains "subexpressions" that are enclosed in parentheses.
Every subexpression forms a group. With the `Groups` property you can access to the various groups captured by the regular expression.

Comment: How does Match.Groups works?  Meaning why is match.Groups[1] give me the number value?  Is it because of the parenthesis in the regular expression?  I checked out this link and it seems that is why its doing that. https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-groups.  Right?

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  I see that the first group is always the original string you are trying to match.

Comment: Yes, actually `match.Groups[0].Value` is always the same as `match.Value`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to replace the number:

```
string fileName = "computerFileHardware20131211";
string pattern = "[0-9]{1,}";
string replacement = "123";

Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

string result = rgx.Replace(fileName , replacement);
```

Comment: Actually I just want to filter it out from the filename.

Comment: @MindGame string result = rgx.Replace(fileName , '');